# QuestDB: select clause with WHERE do not work with timestamp field

Tags: timestamp, where-clause, questdb

On a `Questdb` table I made some queries that are working, but when I tried to apply a `where` clause the field that has a timestamp type:

```
SELECT Timestamp_GMT, ValueCal 
FROM mytable 
WHERE Timestamp_GMT='2020-12-11T11:23:27.583036Z'
```

I got an error message:

```
unexpected argument for function: =. expected args: (STRING,STRING). actual args: (TIMESTAMP,STRING constant)
```

In the database, `Timestamp_GMT` has type `timestamp`
and there are values with format displayed like `2020-12-11T11:23:27.583708Z`

In the documentation, there are examples of where clause applied to timestamps, but I can't see my mistake: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/where

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Timestamp_GMT` is probably not the designated timestamp of the table. Even though it's of type `Timestamp` it can only be filtered as

```sql
Timestamp_GMT=to_timestamp('2020-12-11T11:23:27.583036Z','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ')
```

Designated timestamp is a special column beast. You can do filtering on it
like

```sql
designated_ts='2020-02-26'
```

This actually means not a single value but a range of all microseconds from `00:00:00.000000` to `23:59:59.999999` on Feb 26, 2020.

You can find more details on the [relevant documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/concept/designated-timestamp).

Comment: Since my question I figured out the problem was coming from timestamp which is not designated timestamp (indeed very confusing) but was not able to understand the correct syntax.
Thank you so much for providing the syntax!

Here are the relevant documentation, really take care between timestamp type and deignated timestamp type, they appear the same once you created the table ! 

ttps://questdb.io/docs/concept/designated-timestamp/

https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/timestamp/#during-a-select-operation

https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/where/#timestamp-and-date